# how to implement the % operator for unsigned integer?

Tags: lua, modulo

How to implement the % operator or function for lua's unsigned integer?
I thought of using type cast to float, but precision is a problem.

```
function ModU(a, b)
    if b == 0 then return a end
    if a == 0 then return 0 end

    if b < 0 then
        if a < 0 then
          if a < b then return b-a 
          else return a 
          end
       else 
          return a
       end
    else
        if a > 0 then return math.tointeger(a % b) 
        else 
            i = ModU(x & 0x7fffffff + 1, b)
            j = ModU(2^31 - 1, b)
            return ModU(i + j, b)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: you should represent a as const_0 + const_1*b + const_2*b^2 + ... + const_n*b^n , and when you are done the result is obviously const_0. So you find n, such that b^(n-1)<=a<b^n, and then while a>b^(n-1) a = a - b^(n-1) and then you decrease n by 1. Continue process while a>b

Comment: @bogl i beleive answer should be more formal/completed then my comment; also i am not sure that this is what OP is looking for

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I see. It was just a thought. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function unsigned_mod(x, y)
   return y<=x and x<0 and x-y or y<0 and x or ((x>>1)%y*2+(x&1)-y)%y
end
```

Comment: This function is invalid in lua < 5.3 syntax, so you will want to put it in conditional `load` for code compatible with old lua.

Comment: @val - Of course, this function is applicable only to Lua 5.3+.  The OP's question is about integers in Lua, and Lua prior to 5.3 doesn't have integers.